# How to make website errors display without console errors?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, typeerror

I am making a text changer website https://textchanger.netlify.com/ and ran into a problem when trying to have a error display. I want the error to be displayed whenever the user tries to convert "nothing".

The error does display, and everything to that aspect works fine, but there's some errors in the Chrome console I can't seem to debug.

> Error: `textchanger.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
>       at Scrambler (textchanger.js:43)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (textchanger.js:80)`

If anybody has ideas that'd be awesome!

*JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MysteriousDuck/duc0atjz/*

```js
//Check if textinput is not empty
function fooBar(text) {
    if (document.getElementById("inputText").value == "") {
        console.log('Can not convert nothing!')
    } else {
        capitalizer()
    }
}
return textArray.join(''); {

}

//Capitalize every odd letter
function capitalizer() {
    if (document.getElementById("inputText").value == "") {
        alertify.error('Can not convert nothing!')
    } else {
        var x = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
        var string = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                string = string + x[i].toUpperCase();
            } else {
                string = string + x[i];
            }
        }
        return string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just check in `textchanger.js:80` if variable is not undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is contained within your `scrambler()` function. This function is being **executed every time** a user clicks the `Convert` button **irregardless** of the input they entered into the textarea. This because your event listener is simply listening to clicks on this Convert button and for each click it simply runs the `scrambler()` function based on said input. You need to add input validation check here to fix this from only running on valid input.

**Your Convert Button Listerner:**

```
convertText.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (checkbox_1.checked && checkbox_2.checked) {
    console.log("Capitalizing + Scrambling text");
    document.getElementById("convertedText").value = scrambler(capitalizer());
  } else if (checkbox_2.checked) {
    console.log("Scrambling text");
    var text = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
    document.getElementById("convertedText").value = scrambler(text);
  } else if (checkbox_1.checked) {
    console.log("Capitalizing text");
    document.getElementById("convertedText").value = capitalizer();
  }
})
```

Notice there is **no input validation in this event listener** and it assumes a valid value within your `convertedText` textarea so this is why you're getting the `undefined` error when a user enters nothing to be converted i.e. there is no convertedText to split

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Ahh right. That makes sense. But I wouldn't know how to add such a input validation check. also, in my `function fooBar(text) {` VS code says: `'text' is declared but its value is never read.` how could I fix that? I probably have quite some errors in the website since this is my first ever Javascript using website. lol

Comment: I would use a conditional check i.e. an if statement to check if there is an input to be converted if not just return otherwise run your other conditional logic. The warning you see in VSCode is just linting feedback that you're not using a variable in your code block. If that's actually the case you can simply remove that line of code since it isn't being used. In your case you're not using the text parameter within your fooBar(text) functional declaration.

Comment: @MysteriousDuck np glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

The code `document.getElementById("convertedText").value = scrambler(capitalizer());` throws an error.

`capitalizer()` in the code upper returns `undefined`

Because inside the method fulfills the condition `alertify.error('Can not convert nothing!')` which returns nothing i.e `undefined`

Then `scrambler` tries to **split** a `text` parameter which equal `undefined`